# Can you use both + and - to edit sshd_config option

Tags: openssh

The answers here helped me a lot.

However, in my case, I want to disable some MACs and add a few new ones. Is there a way to do this without hardcoding the options?

The following doesn't work.

```
MACs +hmac-xxxx
MACs -hmac-gggg
```

In this case, only the first statement will have an effect. Is there a way to achieve this without hardcoding?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that.

`ssh` will only consider the first `MACs` (or `Ciphers`, etc) declaration and silently ignore the rest, despite complaining when they're malformed.

You can have a look at the source. In `readconf.c`:

```
        options->macs = NULL;
...
        case oMacs:
                arg = strdelim(&s);
                if (!arg || *arg == '\0')
                        fatal("%.200s line %d: Missing argument.", filename, lin
enum);
                if (*arg != '-' &&
                    !mac_valid(*arg == '+' || *arg == '^' ? arg + 1 : arg))
                        fatal("%.200s line %d: Bad SSH2 MAC spec '%s'.",
                            filename, linenum, arg ? arg : "<NONE>");
                if (*activep && options->macs == NULL)
                        options->macs = xstrdup(arg);
                break;
```

`options->macs` will only be set when it wasn't already set (when it's `NULL`)

Comment: @MaruthKamath I'm afrad you won't get any better that THIS answer, at least until they change openssh and fix it. Until then, NO IS A VALID ANSWER, and you should accept it.